# Create rows for iteration in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to create a report of how long a ticket is open every first of the month, and another that shows how long it took to close a ticket. What is the best way to do this with SQL without creating an interval for each month? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

My current data:

```
| Ticket | Start Date | End Date   |
|--------|------------|------------|
| ABC    | 5/8/2018   | 9/28/2018  |
| XYZ    | 6/22/2018  | 10/15/2018 |
```

Expected result:

```
| Ticket | Start Date | End Date   | Report Date | Ticket Age | Ticket Interval |
|--------|------------|------------|-------------|------------|-----------------|
| ABC    | 5/8/2018   | 9/28/2018  | 6/1/2018    | 24         |                 |
| ABC    | 5/8/2018   | 9/28/2018  | 7/1/2018    | 54         |                 |
| ABC    | 5/8/2018   | 9/28/2018  | 8/1/2018    | 85         |                 |
| ABC    | 5/8/2018   | 9/28/2018  | 9/1/2018    | 116        |                 |
| ABC    | 5/8/2018   | 9/28/2018  | 10/1/2018   |            | 143             |
| XYZ    | 6/22/2018  | 10/15/2018 | 7/1/2018    | 9          |                 |
| XYZ    | 6/22/2018  | 10/15/2018 | 8/1/2018    | 40         |                 |
| XYZ    | 6/22/2018  | 10/15/2018 | 9/1/2018    | 71         |                 |
| XYZ    | 6/22/2018  | 10/15/2018 | 10/1/2018   | 101        |                 |
| XYZ    | 6/22/2018  | 10/15/2018 | 11/1/2018   |            | 115             |
```

Comment: Create a Calendar table (A table with every date for many years that also includes a column called "Report Date" that is the first of that date's month). Then join to it. There's quite a few results on Google if you search "Calendar table sql server" with code for generating one. They are very useful, so it's worth the effort.

Comment: Use a calendar table and join with is using `Calendar.Date between StartDate and EndDate` as a condition. This will give you one row for each day a ticket was opened. After that you can join by the original info and the `year`, `month` columns to get the number of days a ticket was opened in each month.

Comment: Calculating the running total of days is possible using `SUM() OVER...` in SQL Server versions that support it. In previous versions you'd need a subquery. The important thing though is getting the individual day rows from the Calendar table

Comment: `SUM() OVER...` is 2012 and above, so a subquery here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use recursive CTEs:

```
with cte as (
      select ticket, sdate, edate, dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(sdate), sdate)) as reportdate
      from t
      union all
      select ticket, sdate, edate, dateadd(month, 1, reportdate)
      from cte
      where reportdate <= edate
     )
select cte.*, datediff(day, sdate, reportdate) as ticketage,
       (case when datediff(month, edate, reportdate) = 1 then datediff(day, sdate, edate) end) as interval
from cte
order by ticket, reportdate;
```

I included the ticket age on the last month for the ticket.  You can use a similar `case` expression if you really don't want it.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0172c09ce43bef58f671c19c73f89c29) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, your answer works! Only one thing needs to be addressed, final row where the [interval] row is populated, the [ticketage] should be NULL as it is going over the actual age of the ticket and no longer is an open ticket. How can I achieve that?

For eg. Ticket 'ABC', the [ticketage] for [reportdate] '10/1/2018' should be NULL.

Comment: Nevermind, converted the following

'datediff(day, sdate, reportdate) as ticketage'  to 'case when reportdate > edate then null else datediff(day, sdate, reportdate) end as ticketage'